# slider filtering based on class and id

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a div id called 'H1':

```
<div class="header" id="H1"><img src="_img/header/header.png" /></div>
```

And I have another div id of 'backgrd':

```
<div id="backgrd"><img src="_img/hshots/hshot.png" /></div>
```

in javascript how would I say "if the class is called 'header' and the id is called 'H1', then div id 'backgrd' should get its background image from id 'backgrd_2', backgrd_2 is identified in css.

Here is my latest attempt, I have totally confused myself:

```
function H1 
var x ="";
var H1 = document.getElementById("H1");
var _img = document.getElementById("backgrd_2");
    if (H1 == "H1") 
    {
    x=_img
    }
document.getElementById("backgrd").innerHTML=x;
});
```

Comment: Hmm...a bit redundant, if your using `document.getElementById("H1");` -- isn't it pretty obvious that the ID will be `H1` ? :), but you can check the class with `if (H1.className == "header")`

Comment: @tymeJV this is where I am getting confused, I have H1,H2,H3 and H4.  All have the header class.  I am trying to find a way to say if class is header and id is H1.  Then x=_img......I understand now, and it worked, thank you.